# Call full image url instead of stylsheet directory url in JS for Infinite Scroll Function

Tags: jquery, javascript, infinite-scroll

Can`t figure out how to call the gif image with a full url (for example: http:// urltoimage .com/test.gif) **instead of** the stylsheet directory url (obj_test.stylesheet_directory_uri + '/img/ajax-loader.gif').

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

The current code in my custom.js file:

```
    //infinite scroll
    if ($masonry.length && obj_test.infinitescroll != 'disable') {
    nextSelector = obj_test.nextselector;
    if (document.URL.indexOf('/source/') != -1) {
        nextSelector = '#navigation #navigation-next a';
    }

        $masonry.infinitescroll({
        navSelector : '#navigation',
        nextSelector : nextSelector,
        itemSelector : '.thumb',
        prefill: true,
        bufferPx : 500,
        loading: {
            msgText: '',
            finishedMsg: obj_test.__allitemsloaded,
            img: obj_test.stylesheet_directory_uri + '/img/ajax-loader.gif',
            finished: function() {}
        }

    }, function(newElements) {
        if ($('.check-text01').css('float') == 'left') {
            var $newElems = $(newElements).hide();

            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function() {
                $('#infscr-loading').fadeOut('normal');
                $newElems.show();
                $masonry.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
            });
        } else {
            var $newElems = $(newElements);
            $('#infscr-loading').fadeOut('normal');
            $masonry.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunatly my skills are not enough to solve this problem. I researched (googled) and so on - no luck.

Comment: Why? isn't the method `obj_test.stylesheet_directory_uri + '/img/ajax-loader.gif'` giving a dynamic and working path to the GIF anyway?

Comment: This is not my code. In this case it delivers the image from the own content folder of the installation wich gives you more control about the image - you can also deliver it with cdn to. But now i will load the gif from a external source...

Comment: Sounds like a fix, loading from a CDN and providing full path. Or if you have a child theme where you upload `ajax-loader.gif` to `img/` dir, as `obj_test.stylesheet_directory_uri` probably points to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` return

Comment: My Problem is still not solved - if you have any idea, to load the image from a full url - this would be awesome

Comment: isn't it simple as `img: 'https://computerobz.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/when-im-told-that-my-code-is-broken-in-production.gif'` in the `loading` object? did you try such thing?

Comment: does not work - but i found the solution :) see Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
    img: obj_test.stylesheet_directory_uri + '/img/ajax-loader.gif',
```

to

```
    img: "http:// urltoimage .com/test.gif",
```

solve the problem.

**Important** - the url between '...' does not work! The url must be between "..."
That was the problem i dont figured out before :)